# Is anonymous remote attestation viable?

Tags: anonymity, tpm, remote-attestation

I'm currently reading about the TPM and remote attestation. Here's my current understanding of what is happening.

To attest a PCR value to a remote party, the TPM signs the value with an attestation key (AK). This AK is not linkable to the endorsement key (EK) of the TPM, and thus doesn't leak the identity of the TPM. The only information the remote party can derive from the AK is that the measurement was made by an authentic TPM.

Also, the kernel is the only entity of a system that directly communicates with the TPM. All other entities (including the remote party) communicate (directly or indirectly) with the kernel which then in turn communicates with the TPM.

**How can the remote party be sure that the PCR value it received is actually from the desired system A?**

To my understanding the kernel could just forward the attestation request to another system B which runs an unmodified (thus trustworthy) system. The TPM of system B would answer the request, attesting a trustworthy system. The kernel of system A could then just answer the original request with the answer provided by system B. And the remote party would have no chance to know that the attested system state doesn't belong to system A. But would still trust it since the request was in fact made by an authentic TPM.